# Equation, How to remove the bracket of equations?

Tags: equations

How to remove the bracket of D, T, P ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    KG = {(D)\cup(T)\cup(P)\cup(R)\cup(Pr)\cup(CC)\cup(SC)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by bracket? If you mean the parentheses, just delete them.

Comment: Do you mean the equation number, `(1)`?

Comment: Simple delete of the parentheses doesn't work, and it will remove the alphabet, too.

Comment: You would need to put spaces after each `\cup` as well, like `\cup SC`.

Comment: What's the reason for `ltxdoc`?

Comment: deleting `(` just makes ( go, it will not affect anything else. (`ltxdoc` is just for documenting internal latex macro code)

Comment: `KG = {D\cup T\cup P\cup R\cup Pr\cup CC\cup SC}`. You need a space after each `\cup` command. Additional spaces are optional and will not affect the output